# Linqpad and picking up configuration strings from external libraries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, connection-string, linqpad

I just started using LinqPad (v5), and I love it.

But I have one issue with it. I successfully import EntityFramework connection (ObjectContext) from my web project, and when I try to instantiate it like:

```
var db = new SISTEM.Models.DataModelContainer();
```

I get following error:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

I have added connection string (same one from web.config) to both LinqPad.exe.config and LPRun.exe.config, but that did not help, I get the same error.

If I build EntityConnectionString like:

```
var ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
ecsb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = "Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=localhost;initial catalog=BASE;User ID=sa; Password=Elmlodge4;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework";
ecsb.Metadata = "res://*/Models.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.msl";
var db = new SISTEM.Models.DataModelContainer(ecsb.ToString());
```

everything works like a charm.

Most of the time, that is. 
Up until I need to call a function that is located in external library which in turn instantiates my ObjectContext expecting connection string from configuration, which is not picked up.

I hope I explained my problem clearly, and I would appreciate any help in resolving it.

UPDATE:

snippet from my web config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DataModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=locahost;initial catalog=BASE;User ID=sa; Password=Elmlodge4;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I just copy the above into LinqPad configs, I am not sure that it is required.

Milos

Comment: can you show the web.config? Connection strings are "named", the name should match.

Comment: Sure, i'll update it i a bit

Comment: Hmm... shouldn't the provider be `"System.Data.SqlClient"`?

Comment: I'm no EF expert, but that looks like a database first context and there is more to the configuration than just a connection string. Try putting all the EF stuff from your VS config file into the Linqpad config file.

Comment: @Stefan, I have not noticed difference, and I have changed LinqPad configs to SqlClient but no improvement.

Comment: @Crowcoder, yes it is database first object context. But, as you can see, when building in code, i create exactly the same entity connection string, and it works ok. Where should I put connection strings in LinqPad.exe.config, or LPRun.exe.config?

Comment: @MilosMijatovic I tend to put settings in the query's specific config (right-click > app.config) but I don't think it will make a difference where you put it.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Actually, with your last suggestion I am having some progress :) I just pointed to my web.config, and now I can instantiate DataModelContainer. But, strangely, it gives me an error of not able to connect to server, which is obviously not true (triple-checked), when I try to access database.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Sorry, it took fourth check to note a spelling error. So to conclude, it works ok now, when i choose my web.config. Thank a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You mention linqpad.exe.config, but you should be using linqpad.config

From the [FAQ](http://www.linqpad.net/faq.aspx)

> I'm referencing a custom assembly that reads settings from an application configuration file (app.config). How can I tell LINQPad to use this for my query?
>
> The easiest way is to open the Query Properties dialog (F4) and click the app.config tab.
>
> Alternatively, you can create a file called linqpad.config in the same folder as LINQPad.exe. Anything you put here applies to all queries (unless you override it in the dialog above). Don't confuse linqpad.config with linqpad.exe.config:
>
> linqpad.config is for your queries.
>
> linqpad.exe.config is for the LINQPad GUI